# How to enable Collection lexicon in MarkLogic Database server

Tags: marklogic

Could you please provide the Query for enabling the collection lexicon.

I have used this coding but i got same issue.

xquery version "1.0-ml";

```
  import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

  let $config := admin:get-configuration()
  return
  admin:database-set-collection-lexicon($config,
        xdmp:database("myDatabase"), fn:true())
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configurations need to be saved.

See full example here: [admin:save-configuration()](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:save-configuration)

Depending on your configuration changes and situation, we may not want an auto-restart, for which case you would consider: [admin:save-configuration-without-restart()](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:save-configuration-without-restart)

Comment: `admin:save-configuration` will only restart if required, but if you prefer always restarting manually, then yes use `admin:save-configuration-without-restart` instead. Check if the latter returns host ids. It indicates if a restart is required after all.

Comment: if it is working, please help keep StackOverflow clean by accepting the answer. Regards, david